# How many functions $f: A \to B$ such that for all $x \in A$ there exists exactly one $y \in A$ such that $y \ne x$ and $f(x) = f(y)$?

Tags: combinatorics, functions

> How many functions $f$ are there from $A = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ to $B =\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ such that for all $x$ in $A$ there exists exactly one $y$ belonging to $A$ such that $x$ isn’t equal to $y$ and $f(x) = f(y)$?

My attempt:
We basically have to make 3 pairs in domain and give each pair a value from $B$. So

Number of ways of making 3 pairs = $${6}\choose{2,2,2}$$

Number of ways of picking three values from $B$ = $${5}\choose{3}$$

Number of ways of assigning these 3 values to the the pairs = $$3!$$

So total number of functions should be $$90*10*6 = 5400$$

Is this the correct answer?

Comment: Notice that $\binom{6}{2, 2, 2} = \frac{6!}{2!2!2!} = \frac{720}{8} = 90$.

Comment: Ok thanks i made a stupid mistake, s0 5400 is the correct answer?, also I’ll make the correction

Comment: Also, number of ways of assigning these $3$ values to the pairs $=3!=6$, but I believe that was just a typo.

Comment: Your ${6 \choose 2,2,2}$ counts the number of ways to choose three pairs in order from the set of $6$.  For this problem all orders are equivalent, so you must divide by $3!$ which gets you the two answers.  You are counting $(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)$ as different from $(3,4),(1,2),(5,6)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At start you divide $A$ in to 3 pairs.

First pair in $A$ you can choose on ${6\choose 2} = 15$ ways, then choose second pair in $A$, that you can do on ${4\choose 2} = 6$ ways, and you are left with thrid pair. But now we mud divide this by $3!$ since if we choose first pair $X$ then $Y$ and we are left with $Z$ it is the same if e.g. we choose first pair $Z$ then $X$ and finnaly $Y$.

So we can divide $A$ in to 3 pairs on $15$ different ways. Now for specific partition of $A$ on $X$, $Y$, $Z$ we choose one letter for each pair. For pair $X$ we have 5 possibilities, for pair $Y$ 4 and for $Z$ 3.

So we have $$15\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3 = 900$$ good functions.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how $\binom{6}{2,2,2}$ is defined so I'll do it by hand.

First you must indeed determine how many ways there are to pick three pairs. You have 5 ways to make a pair with 1. Let's say you take 2. Then you have 3 ways to make a pair with 3. Let's say you take 4. The last pair has to be the last two numbers. All in all I find **15 ways** to make three pairs.

Then you have to choose three elements out of the five elements of $B$ so that's $\binom{5}{3}$ as you say.

Then you have only $3!$ ways to associate the three pairs with those 3 elements. (3 choices for the first pair, two for the second, and the last pair and element have to be put together)

In the end you get $15 \times 10 \times 6 = 900$ possible functions.

Comment: Can somebody confirm this?

Comment: My logic for making pairs is this, first select two elements in 6C2 ways then select two more out of the 4 left in 4C2 ways and you have the third pair remaining. So total ways of making pairs is 15*6=90

Comment: In that way of thinking, you take into account the order of the pairings. Pairs a,b,c is different from Pairs b,c,a. You have to count those as the same combination, so divide the whole by !3. You then get 90/6=15.

Comment: Typographical error:  The notation $!n$ represents the number of [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) of $n$ objects.  You meant to write $3!$.

Comment: @user601297  The order in which the pairs are chosen does not matter, so you have to divide your answer by the $3!$ orders in which the same three pairs can be selected.  Sorry, I did not notice this earlier.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, got it.

Answer (score 0):

There are only 15 ways to pair up the numbers.
Five choices for 1's partner, then how many ways to pair the remaining four?